# Chat Room title being a url breaks UI

Tags: bug, chat

Not sure if this is the right place to report this bug but I thought it was worth raising.

The following chatroom has a title that is a URL: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99790/https-politics-stackexchange-com-questions-10225-russian-government-warned-nort

This breaks the UI as in the following picture:
[image: Broken UI, not sure how you can see this without a picture though]

Comment: Can't you just edit the description instead having a dev trying to not break 5 browsers and IE11 for over 30 minutes with some CSS hacks?

Comment: @rene sorry I don't use chat rooms on stack overflow until I saw this bug, I'll update it now to fix the issue.

Comment: @rene I think even though there’s a workaround bringing it to the developers’ attention isn’t a bad thing.

Comment: @rene umm... how do you rename it?

Comment: Goto your room  info: https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/1223/data-explorer-sede there should be an edit button if you are an RO. Otherwise ask a mod to do it for you.

Comment: @ColleenV I've only left a comment, didn't dare to abuse my close vote privileges. Before you know it you're public bait here.

Comment: @rene thanks for outlining the process, I am not RO, I will ask a mod to do it for me. Maybe you could post your work around as an answer incase future people are looking for a work around

Comment: Changed the name. Still a bug, though.

Comment: At the risk of splitting hairs: Is the problem that the title was a URL, or is the problem that the title was a single ‘‘word’’ of more than 128 characters (with no spaces)?   And that there were no hyphens in the first 58 characters?

Comment: @Scott it doesn't have to be a URL, WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW will also break it, the css attribute `word-break: break-all;` fixes this for me.